# Using HGFS within VMware to run web server

Tags: apache, vmware

I have VMware running Ubuntu 14.02 and A Windows 8 Host. I've enabled shared folders and installed VMware tools. Now what I want is to run the web server through `/mnt/hgfs/ProjectName`
At this point I can access the shared folder from within Ubuntu. I do not have to run sudo to create new folders or files or edit existing. The folder is not mounted as read only and not treated as read only; however, when I try to change the read only attribute within Windows it reverts back afterwards. Is there any clue as to why the web server cannot read the folder as a web server? Even being mounted as read only the web server should be able to read the files.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the best way to run this is to name the project folder html within vmware and then mount it to the /var/www folder. Now edits have no problem being made and the server runs great for access to both the host and the guest OS.